# What precaution to take when opening malware file using python script

Tags: malware, hash, python

I'm writing a Python script to check the file hash of a malware sample against the VirusTotal database.

At the moment, I'm using a build in open and read functions provided in a standard python library:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        file_sha1 = hashlib.sha1(file.read())
```

I am testing it in a VM to ensure my host system is not compromised. But I am wondering would Python script that reads the file in binary form execute the file or is it just reading the binary content and there is no chance of executing the file, thus not compromising my machine.

When dealing with malware it is better to be safe than sorry I was wondering are there any precautions to take in my project.

Comment: This is a pure programming question since you are asking how Python's `open()` works. The fact that you are writing this for malware analysis doesn't matter.

Comment: Using `open()` certainly will not execute the file.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: Thank you @itprorh66 my question is more on how the malware works, and does reading it in binary or getting the hash can trigger the payload. I think it would be more suited in security.stackexchange.com but it was migrated here.
I could not be more specific since I do not know what I don't know, But I understand that it is too broad of a question for stack exchange.
If you can just mark it as too broad and close it. Thanks.

Comment: We can't answer how malware works, because that would be like asking how any random program that we can't look at works.  It works however it wants to work.  And malware written just for you probably won't be in VirusTotal, so that's no guarantee either.  Best bet is to do supply chain verification.

Comment: As already stated, reading the malware in binary form with open() doesn't execute it, it just loads it into a buffer.  Unless some analysis you do on it in that buffer has a security hole that causes foreign code to be executed, it's not a hazard (yet).  For example, a bug in a zip library could (and has) caused problems like that.